# Is it possible to create a UTM tag within a URL without having to reload a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some elements in my webpage and would like to track via UTM if the user interacts by clicking on these elements. Basicaly, as the user clicks on any of these elements, a UTM is automaticaly added to the URL without reloading the page.

The reason is that I can only acquire that information via Google Analytics, in order to track the user behaviour.

Comment: That sounds like a really weird requirement? Why would you need the UTM to be part of the URL's

Comment: Dynamically changing the URL via something such as `history.pushState()` will not provide information on a page that has already been loaded to Google Analytics

Comment: Hi @Brad ! Thanks for the answer! 
Actually I do not want to track the user in that specific page. This is a work around for an e-commerce and what I am willing to track is if the person who interacted with that specific element on the page ended up buying something from this store. So that is the reason I thought of including an UTM. Easier to track through GA. 
In this case I believe you suggestion should work, right @Brad?

Comment: Hi @adeneo, please, see my reply above.  :-)